# Let $g\in R[a,b]$, $f$ a bounded function and $(x_n)$ a sequence, such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, $x\neq x_n$. Then $f\not\in R[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I was asked to get an example where $f$ does not accomplish be Riemann integrable.

> Let $g:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function and $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function and $(x_n)$ a sequence of points on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, $x\neq x_n$. Show with an example that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

This question sounds a little weird, I have been trying to get functions with these properties but I am not sure at all. I thought in something like $f(x)=\cos x$ and its McLaurin series ($g(x)$), but I did not get anything. Could you suggest something?

Comment: "except at many points on $[a,b]$" The number of points matters , how many points do you want to change?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, the question does not specify the quantity. In the original proof I assumed a partition with $n$ points where the condition was not accomplish.

Comment: If you modify a Riemann integrable function only at finitely many points, both the integrability and the value of integral will be preserved. The problem needs to clarify whether the modification is allowed only at finitely points or at infinitely many points...

Comment: I see. In that case, I am quite confident that the second statement concerns $f$ being different from $g$ at *finitely* many points, and the first statement concerns $f$ being different from $g$ at *infinitely* many points. If you change finitely many points, Riemann integrability is intact. If you change infinitely many points (particularly values at the rationals or some dense subset) then Riemann integrability will fail. Compare the zero function, with the indicator function of the rational numbers.

Comment: The title really needs to be changed—in isolation it is self-contradictory.

Comment: For the question in your body you have an easy counter-example. Let $g$ be $0$ everywhere and $x_n$ represent the enumeration of rationals in $[0,1]$. Let $f(x_n) =1$ and $f(x) =0$ if $x\neq x_n$. Then $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ does not exist.